# Как сделать невидимую рамку вокруг окна для изменения размера, таская края рамки? (WPF приложение)

Tags: c#, wpf

По умолчанию рамка есть, но она маленькая. В WindowChrome получается сделать только внутри окна, задав свойство ResizeBorderThickness="10". Я пробовал вместе с установкой свойства задать шаблон окна, положив в шаблон border со свойствами BorderBrush = "Transparent" и BorderThickness="10", но не работает. Так же у меня стоит AllowsTransparency="True".

```
<Window x:Class="AccountStorage.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AccountStorage"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        WindowStyle="None" Height="450" Width="800" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="50" ResizeBorderThickness="10" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="White"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Заранее благодарю за решение!

Comment: XAML разметку вы конечно же не покажете.

Comment: Не описывайте код словами, это из разряда "у меня есть кофта в горошек" и вот сиди и представляй, какого она пошива, цвета и так далее. Говорите про код, прикладывайте его, а уж затем, всячески расписывайте что и как. Сейчас я могу лишь предположить, что значение `ResizeBorderThickness` слишком мало. То есть это значение работает от начала окна, а не от конца его рамки. Другими словами, значение `ResizeBorderThickness` должно быть `BorderThickness+нужное(10)`.

Comment: добавил код в описание

Comment: Почитайте еще раз мой комментарий. `ResizeBorderThickness = BorderThickness+нужное(10)`